# paypal notify_url is empty even though it is passed on the form

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

imn submitting this form to send users to recurring payments registration

```
      <form name='_xclick' id='_xclick' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick-subscriptions'>
        <input type='hidden' name='business' value='xxxxx@gmail.com'>
        <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
        <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='a3' value='90.00'>
        <input type='hidden' name='p3' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='t3' value='M'>
        <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='customerId=F5C311'>
        <input type='hidden' name='src' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='sra' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='xxxxx'>
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.xxxxxx.com/package-success?pplstatus=0&amp;customerId=F5C311'>
        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.xxxxxx.com/package-success?pplstatus=1&amp;customerId=F5C311'>
        <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.xxxxxx.com/package-success?pplstatus=IPN&amp;pplstatus=0&amp;customerId=F5C311'>
        <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
      </form>
    <script>document.forms['_xclick'].submit();</script>
```

for some mysterious reason when i check PayPal IPN history the notify URL is empty and of course that payment is not being processed on my system (attached the PayPal message info).
Message delivery is Enabled and as URL i have written http://www.xxxxxxx.com/?pplstatus=IPN

[image: PayPal IPN message info]

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hi Lior, I'm having IPN issues lately and this is what I'm experiencing as well. Interested in what you find out!

Comment: i have raised a question to Paypal support - hopefully it will take them less than 1 year to respond :-)

Comment: Under a day! Can you include your ticket# so that I can close this off on our end as well?

Comment: i take it back then ... it was indeed very quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that we're currently working to resolve. IPN messages will still send as normal, but the IPN history page may not reflect the right state / notify_url details.

**edit:** This has been resolved as of 29/04. Please let me know if you run into any further issues.

Comment: well thanks :-)
thing is that im not sure the IPN is really calling the right URL - do you have an estimation on when it will be fixed ?

Comment: ticket number - 130421-000034

Comment: I have the exact same issue, please help.

Comment: this issue seems to be more than just the notify_url missing - i cant also see the message and im not really sure that calls are being made correctly, do you have a timeline for fixing this ?

Comment: This will be resolved early next week. Messages are definitely being sent however; only the display of messages is affected.

Comment: This has been resolved as of yesterday. Please let me know if you run into any further issues.

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problem which I have described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174275/why-paypal-does-not-call-my-notify-url-but-on-sandbox-everything-works

But my status is Retrying and my IPN is not being called. I really don't know what is going on.

Comment: Linked question has been removed.